# Matrix Vector Multiplication Parallel

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, concurrency, multiplication

CLRS book has the following algorithm for parallel for matrix vector multiplication 
[image]

My problem is, can't we use a simple approach like this,

```
MAT-VEC-MULTIPLY-MAIN(A,x,y,n)
    for i = 2 to n
        spawn MULTIPLY-ROW(A,x,y,n,i)

    MULTIPLY-ROW(A,x,y,n,1)     
    sync   

MULTIPLY-ROW(A,x,y,,n,row)
    for j = 1 to n
        y[row] = y[row] + a[row]j.xj
```

Both approaches generate same number of threads (One thread for each row). Is there any performance difference between these two?

Comment: Can you profile them and see?